# Locate a button by css and buttonText

Tags: protractor

I have some buttons with the same text on the same page,
how can i locate one of them if I want to use both element(by.buttonText("")) and element(by.css(""))?

thanks

Comment: Something like this? `var element = element.all(by.buttonText("")).element(by.css(""));` I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your approach and how your HTML tag looks like.
If there is a unique attribute, you can use that.
e.g. `element(by.cssContainingText('[class="something unique"]', 'Button 1'))`

Another way is to get the element or DIV holding the button.
e.g. `element(by.id('DIV-ID')).element(by.buttonText('Button 1'))`

If you can share your html tag, it would be much easier.